# How to insert collection view sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know how to insert items, just like this:

```
let insertionIndex = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
collectionView.insertItems(at: [insertionIndex])
```

but for sections it uses `IndexSet` to insert sections, which confuses me, can somebody demonstrate how to create a valid `IndexSet` and insert a section at that index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `IndexSet` with an array literal:

```
let i: IndexSet = [1, 2, 4]
```

or if you already have an `[Int]`, you can pass that to the `IndexSet` constructor:

```
let array = [4, 5, 6]

let i2 = IndexSet(array)
```

So, if you want to insert a new section at index `0`, you would just call:

```
collectionView.insertSections([0])
```